# Bq command line error in compute engine VM instance CENTOS7

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I'm running a VM instance (google compute engine) with CENTOS 7, everytime i run the bq command, i keep getting error. I supposed bq is by default in compute engine.

```
[username@instance-1 ~]$ bq
Error initializing bq client: service_account
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/pyglib/appcommands.py", line 805, in _CommandsStart
    sys.modules['__main__'].main(GetCommandArgv())
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py", line 6078, in main
    if FLAGS.debug_mode or FLAGS.headless:
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/absl/flags/_flagvalues.py", line 468, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: debug_mode
FATAL error in main: debug_mode
Run 'bq.py help' to get help
[username@instance-1 ~]$ bq --format=prettyjson dataset.tableid
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'use_gce_service_account'
Run 'bq.py help' to get help
[username@instance-1 ~]$
```

my compute engine account has full full access to all Cloud APIs, in addition just to be sure, i also add bigquery admin in the IAM part.

I'm not really sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference):

> The bq authorization flags are deprecated. To configure authorization
>   for the bq command-line tool, see  [Authorizing Cloud SDK tools](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing).

and also in this section you can find flag that cause an error:

> --use_gce_service_account

I've tried to run at my linux machine with Google Cloud SDK command `bq` and it works perfectly:

```
$ bq        
Python script for interacting with BigQuery.


USAGE: bq.py [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]


Any of the following commands:
  cancel, cp, extract, get-iam-policy, head, help, init, insert, load, ls, mk, mkdef, partition, query, rm, set-iam-policy, shell,
  show, update, version, wait
```

At first, you should [update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#updating_components) your Cloud SDK to the latest version (or reinstall it) and check again. Also, please update your post with version of your Cloud SDK:

```
$ gcloud info       
Google Cloud SDK [277.0.0]

Python Version: [3.7.5rc1 (default, Dec 20 2019, 17:52:56)  [GCC 8.3.0]]
Python Location: [/usr/bin/python3]
```

If you have en error with the latest Cloud SDK, try set up default values for `bq` in `$HOME/.bigqueryrc` as it described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags).

In addition, I'd recommend you to check/update Python if nothing helps.

**EDIT** You can set up defaults in your `~/.bigqueryrc` file like this:

```
project_id = --my-project-id--
```

in your favorite text editor like `nano` or `vim`. Keep in mind that file paths in `.bigqueryrc` had to be the full path.

**EDIT2** Have a look at the Cloud SDK [system requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install):

> It requires Python **2.7.9** or higher.

and you have **2.7.5**.

**UPDATE** Deleting  and reinstalling the Cloud SDK solved the problem.

Comment: i have already did the authentication earlier, and my service account is authenticated.I tried running the gcloud info and i got this result ```Google Cloud SDK [277.0.0]

Platform: [Linux, x86_64] ('Linux', 'username', '3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64', '#1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 
2019', 'x86_64', 'x86_64')
Locale: ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
Python Version: [2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]]
Python Location: [/usr/bin/python2]
Site Packages: [Disabled] ```
 how to access the .bigqueryrc? can you please provide more guidance on this?

Comment: You can find un the documentation that "you must first create a .bigqueryrc file. You can use your preferred text editor to create the file" https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags. For example `nano ~/.bigqueryrc`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It looks like the cause of your issue is outdated Python.

Comment: i'm running instance in another computer with python 2.7.5 and it's working fine, so it might not be the python version. I managed to get to create the .bigqueryrc, but not sure what else i should put there to make the bq command works. And what do you mean by full path? Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: id also like to ask how did you update your python? i followed this https://www.osetc.com/en/how-to-install-the-latest-python-3-3-6-x-3-7-x-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7.html  but when i typed gcloud info, i still get the old version. Also, im running on google cloud engine, I don't need to do additional authentication right? but i still get the ```Error initializing bq client: service_account```

Comment: Full path means that if you decided to use some tokens inside `.bigqueryrc` you shoud use something like this `/home/user/token` instead of `~/token`. As I can see, CentOS sticks to old version of Python because os system utilities like `yum` (it's hard to say as I prefer Debian based distros). Try to run `bq init`, despite it's not recommended way to fill `.bigqueryrc`, but you can try.

Comment: i tried running the bq init command, and i still get the error.  ```[username@instance-1 ~]$ bq init
It looks like you are trying to run "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bq.py init".
The "init" command is no longer needed with the Cloud SDK.
To authenticate, run gcloud auth.
Really run this command? (y/N) y
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'use_gce_service_account'
Run 'bq.py help' to get help
```

Comment: Please show me your `~/.bigqueryrc`. Have you tried to delete completely Cloud SDK and then install it again and initialize?

Comment: i only have this ```project_id = --my-project-id--
service_account = --my-client-id--@developer.gserviceaccount.com
``` I will try to delete and install the cloud sdk and let you know

Comment: deleting the old installation and reinstalling the sdk solved the problem! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bash alias acting wrong or a `~/.bigqueryrc`

Check the syntax and the correct service account files inside `~/.bigqueryrc`

Comment: i ran the command, and i got error , ```bash: /home/username/.bigqueryrc: No such file or directory ```  I dont know how to solve this issue.

Comment: How do I get to ~/.bigqueryrc? where to find it?